# como guardar la figura como tipo pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

tengo vectores llamados eje_x, vector_y, y2, y3
los grafico pero necesito guardar la imagen como pdf

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
eje_x = np.arange(0,5,1)
vector_y = [5,8,2,1,9]
y2 = [4,3,5,6,8]
y3 = [7,5,4,6,1]
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.plot(eje_x,y2,eje_x,vector_y,'ro')
plt.legend(['ajuste grado 2','y original'])
plt.xlabel("eje x")
plt.ylabel("eje y")
plt.title("grafico fit grado2")
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.plot(eje_x,y3,eje_x,vector_y,'ro')
plt.legend(['ajuste grado 3','y original'])
plt.xlabel("eje x")
plt.title("grafico fit grado3")
```

usando subplot me quedan los dos gráficos pero no se como guardarlos en pdf

Comment: podrias intentar con plt.savefig(filename1 +  ".pdf")

Comment: plt.savefig(graficos.pdf)

NameError: name 'graficos' is not defined, me sale esto al intentar guardarlo asi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

eje_x = np.arange(0, 5, 1)
vector_y = [5, 8, 2, 1, 9]
y2 = [4, 3, 5, 6, 8]
y3 = [7, 5, 4, 6, 1]
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
print("entro")
plt.plot(eje_x, y2, eje_x, vector_y, 'ro')
plt.legend(['ajuste grado 2', 'y original'])
plt.xlabel("eje x")
plt.ylabel("eje y")
plt.title("grafico fit grado2")
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(eje_x, y3, eje_x, vector_y, 'ro')
plt.legend(['ajuste grado 3', 'y original'])
plt.xlabel("eje x")
plt.title("grafico fit grado3")
```

Lo unico que se faltaba a tu codigo era guardar en el archivo que necesitabas

al ponerlo asi

```
plt.savefig(graficos.pdf)
```

python lo interpreta como que tienes algo definido como graficos.pdf

al ponerlo entre comillas

`plt.savefig("graficos.pdf")` le dices a plt como lo vas a guardar y el solo crear el archivo con la extencion que tu pusiste, incluso podrias poner

```
plt.savefig("graficos.png")
```

y este lo guardaria en png

eso fue todo.

Comment: así si funciona, me puedes explicar que hiciste porfavor

Comment: listo, realmente estabas completo